# Швейная машина или машинка?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как грамотнее сказать: "швейная машина" или "машинка"? "Машина" для нее как-то слишком громко, по-моему)))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, согласна с вами, употребление "швейная машинка" привычнее. Но словарь сочетаемости рядом с определением машина -  "механизм, который совершает какую-либо полезную работу путем преобразования одного вида энергии в другой" дает рядом со словом определения швейная, стиральная, холодильная, печатная и др. Так что возможны, на мой взгляд, оба варианта.

Comment: Я представляю себе, как легко запутаться иностранцу. Вязальная швейная машинка супротив вязаной шейной манишки)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, конечно "машина". Но разве кто-то запрещал использование уменьшительного варианта даже в отношении "машины"? 
Вопрос из серии "как правильно: малый или маленький"?

Answer (score 0):

Всё-таки правильнее, на мой взгляд, "машинка" - из-за того, что она размещается на столе (а если она ножная, то уже "машина"). На бумагоделательную машину язык не повернётся сказать "машинка". Автомобиль - машина, а игрушка - машинка, хотя чаще говорят "машина", потому что уже есть уменьшительное слово "игрушка". Мне думается, что это сочетание ("швейная машина") - ещё неустоявшееся, оно пока ещё ищет свою определённую нишу в языке.